# Keycloak Server info page for proivder info

Tags: java, docker, maven, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am working on Keycloak SPI to make a custom endpoint. For my project I want to send an email invite to someone with an build-in link. But first I need to know how to deploy a keycloak container with a build-in SPI. So I began with making an event that will send an email when an user is logged in (just for testing purposes). I found this as example but he uses registration: https://github.com/zene22/keycloak-spi-example.

My question is how to see in the web UI the following screenshot from the github's README

[image: website screenshot]

He says to go to the list of providers on the server-info page. But I can not seems to find the server-info page.

Anyone any clue on how to get to that page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get to the server info page click on the admin on the top right of your screen.

[image: keycloak top bar]

This will give a small menu with a link to the server info page.